# Save phylo tree made by phylobase and plot it together with additional data

Tags: ape, ape-phylo

I have a phylogenetic tree that I created with phylobase and it contains additional data (traits). But I'm having trouble saving it in nex or newick format.
I tried saving with ape, but ape deleted all the additional data I had. I need that data to be plotted together with a phylogenetic tree.
I have also tried to directly plot without saving, and that doesn't work because it is an unrooted tree.
I have the rooted tree.
But I'm confused about solving this.
I want to plot it based on a rooted tree with the data in the unrooted tree. However, this unrooted tree cannot be saved.
What do I have to do?

Plotting phylo tree together with some traits.

This is screenshot of my unrooted tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwnrA.jpg)

This is my rooted tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH7I9.jpg)

Comment: In the future please copy/paste/format the output of `str(my_object)` for a similar question - it's easier to read than image links.

Answer (score 0):

From your images your rooted tree is a `"phylo"` object and not a `"phylo4d"` object. You can plot `"phylo"` objects using:

```
ape::plot.phylo(my_tree)
```

And save them using `write.tree` (newick) or `write.nexus` (nexus)

```
ape::write.tree(my_tree, file = "my_tree.tre")
ape::write.nexus(my_tree, file = "my_tree.nex")
```